Can cloud-init install a remotely hosted package with a url that's not in a repository?
I have a package hosted remotely as either a deb or rpm. Does cloud-init support installing packages from hard-coded remote locations. I'm wanting to install GitLab CLI on machines I spin up but GitLab doesn't provide a repository.

Workaround with runcmd
One method to work around this, if the feature doesn't exist is to use runcmd,
You can use this to yum install or curl and hand the package to dpkg,
runcmd:
 - [ ls, -l, / ]
 - [ sh, -xc, "echo $(date) ': hello world!'" ]
 - [ sh, -c, echo "=========hello world=========" ]
 - ls -l /root
 # Note: Don't write files to /tmp from cloud-init use /run/somedir instead.
 # Early boot environments can race systemd-tmpfiles-clean LP: #1707222.
 - mkdir /run/mydir
 - [ wget, "http://slashdot.org", -O, /run/mydir/index.html ]

